# Kentico CustomTableForm - Save records to a custom table

Tags: kentico

I am very new to Kentico. I have been saddled with a project of recreating a spreadsheet as part of a Kentico built website. I need to accept input from a form, and do calculations and then spit the results back on the screen for the end-user. Again...I am very new to Kentico. So I have been trying to use a custom table, and a custom-table-form. I have it saving an initial record to the custom table, but it overwrites it each time. What would be a proper way of taking in an end-users values from a form and being able to preform basic CRUD tasks with that data (and then display it back on the page for the user to see)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@Tom,

Please try with [Custom Table Input Edit web part](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/web-parts/custom-table-input-edit) from Kentico Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [the rest service](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/manipulating-data-using-rest/managing-objects-using-rest)
you can have table url like `~/rest/customtableitem.customtable.sampletable?format=json`
and then do all CRUD operations.

The other way if you are new (my suggestion) is to start with examples (install corporate site example locally if you don't have it ). Check the `/Examples/Web-parts/Custom-tables/` section it has all the example how to deal with a custom table. For editing you can use combination: custom table you should use *custom table repeater*, *object management buttons* and *custom table form*. Install the the example (even with the trial version)

Comment: Peter, thank you.  However I had tried Vasu's suggestion above and it will work for our needs.  Thanks!